# image overflow 2 divs in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, overflow

I wondered if there is a opportunity to get the logo of the following site like in this picture?

http://vintagemaedchen.de/

[image]

unfortunately I couldnt find a way to add a class or an ID to the logo.

thanks :-)

Comment: Try something by yourself, or at least share the related piece of code. Otherwise this will be closed as offtopic (read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your CSS like this

```
#header > .container {
  height: 230px;                  /*  less high than image make it overflow below  */
}
#header {
  margin-bottom: 80px!important;  /*  increase the green elements margin some  */
}
```

*Side note:*

*It is sometimes tempting to use `position: absolute` for these kind of things, **don't**, it most likely will give you issues later down the road, often with unwanted element overlapping.*

Comment: You guys are great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with positioning a little bit (see below:)

```
#header > .container {
  bottom: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100% !important;
}
header#header {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

That would give you this: [image: this]

Comment: Thats awesome!
Do you know how to enlarge the padding between logo and the article section below to get this green line bigger?

Comment: Hi @KrystianManthey, what LGSon's answer shows is correct - you need to increase the `margin-bottom` on your `#header` to grow the height of the green line :)